# I didn't set path for css, but the css effect is working , why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

There is nothing in application.css.

I have put a file named "cake.generic.css" in app/assets folder. If i load the home page the cake.generic.css is loading and working staraightway. Why is it working. I didn't set this path in application.html.erb.

```
<head>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline

http://railscasts.com/episodes/282-upgrading-to-rails-3-1

Comment: I commented these lines, othwerwise, i get error from rails s, group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
end

Comment: If i put the css and js files in app/public, then how can i set/configure path to load css and js from app/public folder ?

Comment: I still can't understand why the css are files automatically loaded .

Comment: it is a feature of Rails 3.1 -- they completely re-did how the assets (e.g. CSS) are processed / generated / loaded.  Rails makes also some assumptions, that if you have  layout with the same name as your controller, that it will load that layout and CSS files automatically, if they are named according to the Rails convention..  check: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html towards the end

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 3.1, there is an asset pipeline (check Rails guides).

Basically, in your application.css, all css files are required by default. It lets you have a nice unique and compressed file in production

Comment: Where is that configuration for all css files are required ?

Comment: In application.css, you have a require statement

Comment: What do these line do ?  *= require_self
 *= require_tree